# How to show multiple error line which using Formik and yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have tried to write the multiple error line which is using `formik` and `yup` validation. After use `this.createError()` it turns error message as string not array as `{errors: '4 errors occurred'}`.

example code that I did:

```
const messages = [
  { key: "length", message: "should have  password at least 8 characters" },
  { key: "notRepeat", message: "should not repeat old password" }
];

this.createError({
  path: `${this.path}`,
  message: messages,
  errors: messages
});
```

What I need to be is errors that I need it to return as messages([]) Constance then I show a list of error thru UI.

Any comments or suggestions to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const errors = messages.map((msg) => ({
  path: this.path,
  message: msg.message,
}));

this.createError(errors);
```